# htaccess conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Need some advanced redirecting with a .htaccess rule

This is my current rule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/session.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path_maps.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css|swf)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer1\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer2\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer3\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer4\.com


RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

This rule directs all traffic not in the RewriteCond to `www.example.com`.
However I now need the following amendment,
if this:

`/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van.*`

path gets visited then I want it to redirect the `www.example.com/van`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I would do is to simply this.  First adding .* at the end of a pattern is redundant, and if you want to test if a URI ends with `.swf` say then you use `\.swf$`.  Also combine rules where sensible.

Next the simplest way to do a blanked exclusion is to use a "^ -", which is just a shorthand for "always do nothing" (if the conds are satisfied).  Adding an [L] means that the following rules don't get used.  Alternatively you can skip the next N rules by using [skip=N].

And specify a base, e.g. / if the `.htaccess` is in DOCROOT, So:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
#
# No redirects for a specific list of dealers, paths and file types
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.(dealer1|dealer2|dealer3|dealer4)\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|login|session|path_maps)\b          [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|png|js|css|swf)^
RewriteRule ^              -                                            [L]
#
# Otherwise redirect var URIs to /van
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van
RewriteRule ^              http://www.domain.com/van                    [R=301,L]
#
# Redirect everything except truck to /
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck.*
RewriteRule ^              http://www.domain.com                        [R=301,L]
```

Lastly, I am really suspicious of your long URIs.  The request URI everything excluding the server and query bits (e.g. for `http//server/abc/login?user=fred` it is `/abc/login`).  For example you really want to redirect everything other this path at this site to the new domain?

> `http://www.domain.com/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck`

Forcing users to use such complex URIs is a good way to discourage their visiting!

Answer (score 0):

After your current rule, just add this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer1\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer2\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer3\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dealer4\.com

RewriteRule ^/?content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van.* http://www.domain.com/van [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. That works but now the dealer domain redirects too and it should not. Example: www.dealer.com/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van

Comment: @user1402381 see my edit, you just need to add the same host conditions as your other rules.